# ¿Cómo puedo combinar dos diccionarios manteniendo valores?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo dos ficheros YAML con información. Uno de ellos contiene información genérica `generico.yml` y luego hay otro que es más específico, pues dependerá del entorno en el que trabaje (pro, dev...), llamémosle `produccion.yml`.

generico.yml:

```
futbol:
    jugadores: 11
    arbitros: 4
baloncesto:
    jugadores: 5
```

produccion.yml:

```
baloncesto:
    arbitros: 2
balonmano:
    jugadores: 5
    arbitros: 3
```

Como veis, contienen campos similares y la idea es que se cargue `generico.yml` y luego `produccion.yml`, para que la información del 2.º sobreesriba la del 1.º para tener finalmente unos valores del tipo:

```
futbol:
    jugadores: 11
    arbitros: 4
baloncesto:
    jugadores: 5
    arbitros: 2
balonmano:
    jugadores: 5
    arbitros: 3
```

Actualmente tengo algo del tipo:

```
import yaml

# Carga configuración genérica
f_generico = 'generico.yml'
with open(f_generico) as f:
    conf_generico = yaml.safe_load(f)

# Carga configuración específica de entorno
f_pro = 'produccion.yml'

with open(f_pro) as f:
    conf_pro = yaml.safe_load(f)

# Combina los valores
config = {**conf_generico, **conf_pro}
```

Por lo que los valores una vez cargados son los siguientes diccionarios:

```
conf_generico = {'baloncesto': {'jugadores': 5}, 'futbol': {'arbitros': 4, 'jugadores': 11}}
conf_pro = {'baloncesto': {'arbitros': 2}, 'balonmano': {'arbitros': 3, 'jugadores': 5}}
```

Sin embargo, a la hora de combinar los diccionarios uso [`{**conf_generico, **conf_pro}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961) y, como es obvio, junta por índices y, por tanto, se carga lo que ya había en `generico.yml` si lo encuentra en `produccion.yml` y `config` contiene:

```
{
  "baloncesto": {
    "arbitros": 2  # ¡falta 'jugadores'!
  },
  "balonmano": {
    "arbitros": 3,
    "jugadores": 5
  },
  "futbol": {
    "arbitros": 4,
    "jugadores": 11
  }
}
```

¿Existe alguna manera de realizar esta unión de diccionarios preservando índices y valores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un `for` para recorrer el diccionario e ir actualizando uno por uno:

```
config = conf_generico.copy() # copias el diccionario para no modificar el conf_generico 

for k,v in conf_pro.items(): # recorres los items de la nueva configuración
    config[k] = {**config.get(k, {}), **v} # sobreescribes la configuración k con una nueva.

print(config)
```

El detalle está en obtener el valor actual para unirlo con el nuevo `config.get(k, {})` (como puede no tener un valor actual, usamos un diccionario vacío `{}` por defecto).

Ese valor, lo unimos con los nuevos que estan en `v`: `{**config.get(k, {}), **v}` y lo remplazamos el valor anterior.